# Replace spaces with a dash in a URL

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I managed to replace special characters such as : ; / etc in my URL but now it has the spaces again. Here is my code:

```
<h3><a href="<?php echo (isset($row_getDisplay['post_id']) ? $row_getDisplay['post_id'] : ''); ?>_<?php echo str_replace(array(':', '\\', '/', '*'), ' ', urldecode($row_getDisplay['title'])); ?>.html" ><?php echo (isset($row_getDisplay['title']) ? $row_getDisplay['title'] : ''); ?></a></h3>
```

I want it to like it is remove special characters as well as replace spaces with dashes.

Comment: It's quite obvious you now have spaces since you put them there yourself with: `str_replace(array(':', '\\', '/', '*'), ' ', urldecode($row_getDisplay['title']));`. Replace it with "nothing", e.g.: `str_replace('yourChar', '', 'yourString');`. After that you can replace the remaining spaces with dashes.

Answer (score 52):

Try `str_replace(' ', '-', $string);`

Comment: simplest solution, you can add array of invalid characters like str_replace(array(" ", ";"), array("-", "_"), $str)

Comment: Am I the worst for overlooking any preg_replace solution when there are more straight and simpler options? Like yours? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 27):

You can use preg_replace:

```
preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', '-', $subject);
```

This will replace all instances of space with a single '-' dash. So if you have a double, triple, etc space, then it will still give you one dash.

EDIT: this is a generec function I've used for the last year to make my URLs tidy

```
    function formatUrl($str, $sep='-')
    {
            $res = strtolower($str);
            $res = preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]]/', ' ', $res);
            $res = preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', $sep, $res);
            return trim($res, $sep);
    }
```

It will convert all non-alphanumeric characters to space, then convert all space to dash, then trim any dashes on the end / beginning of the string. This will work better than having to list special characters in your str_replace

Comment: Thanks I will try that in a minute, how would I include the generec function into my code,

Comment: Put it in a file (eg "helpers.php") and include it in your code at the beginning of file with <?php require_once('helpers.php'); ?> before you call the function. This way you can reuse it in multiple files without having to type out or declare the function in each file.

Comment: So just put it in a file 'helpers.php' include the page in the code and that's it?